# can we use combination of kendoUI web and kendoUI dataviz

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

In my application,I have used all widgets in "KendoUI web",now i want to implement bar chart,so can i use both "kendo dataviz" in my application,I have implemented this ,I am able to load either "bar chart" or other "web" widgets at a time.so can u tell me is it possible to use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there was an issue in the previous versions, did you try with the latest version (Q2 sp - 913)?

Also there is a script called **kendo.all.min.js** which contains the [dataviz/mobile/web](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies) frameworks into single file which  you can use.

Here is is the CDN :

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```